# What size Schluter linear shower drain should I use?

Tags: shower, drain

I’m installing the 38” x 76” Schluter linear drain shower tray. I purchased the 35-7/16” linear drain which will give about 1.5” on each side which I’m a bit worried about how to fit tile into that small gap. Should I go with the 31-1/2” linear drain or even the 23-5/8”? With the smaller sizes I’d just have to make sure it’s sloped inward on each side. The drain will be up against the wall.

Comment: Have a nice little accent strip of 3/4" square glass mosiac tile at each end of the shower drain, and you can fit TWO WHOLE TILES in 1.5" easy peasy.

Comment: @Ecnerwal great idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a single answer to this question. It comes down to a combination of your shower dimensions, the tile that you are using, and user preference.

They also make a linear drain that you can cut down to fit from 10 inches up to 8 feet called [Kerdi-line-vario](https://resources.schluter.com/media/psi/lowes/KERDI%20line%20VARIO%20Brochure.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn’t aware of the vario. Let’s say the tile is 2x2 mosaic and the inside width of the shower is 38”. Is there any reason the 23-5/8” drain up against the wall would not work properly?

Comment: As long as it has some slope, I don't see why not.